# Users from on-prem AD aren't synced to Azure AD as Guest

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a setup where I have installed the Azure AD on-prem cloud provisioning agent on a Domain joined server. The setup was successful. I followed the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/cloud-provisioning/how-to-prerequisites

After configuring the agent in Azure AD, Users can only be synced as Member.
Is there a way to sync users as Guest using the provisioning agent?

Also, is there a Microsoft Graph API to validate the agent and do the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

On-prem AD isn't synced to Azure AD as Guest and those synced users cannot be a Guest user and it's as per design.

You can invite guest users to the directory, to a group, or to an application. After you invite a user through any of these methods, the invited user's account is added to Azure Active Directory (Azure AD), with a user type of Guest. The guest user must then redeem their invitation to access resources. Any user sync via AD connect will not be a guest user.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! Is it possible to sync the users to MIM and then onboard them to Azure AD as Guests from MIM? Also, is there an API to do the agent configuration?

Comment: Though we use MIM, we can synchronize users between different directories but not as a guest user. Refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal) for adding guest users in Azure AD. Usually, the Guest user's concept can be used only for external partner organizations. There is no specific API to sync users to Azure as a guest through AD connect or MIM.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to follow these directions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/hybrid-on-premises-to-cloud

You first has to enable the synchronization of the UserType attribute within the Synchronization Rules Editor.  Since there is no UserType attribute in AD DS, you derive the value from some other attribute.  So, you could use an ExtensionAttribute value for this (you can make these multi-value by using a delimiter, such as a semi-colon) or you could look at the UPNs of the users and device the UserType based on the domain part of the UPN.  Using the domain part can be rather tedious, especially if you have many UPN suffixes in your own domain.  I personally would use a ExtensionAttribute and by default sync users as a "Member" (which is a default, normal user synced to Azure AD), and then watch for a value of "userType=Guest" in the ExtensionAttribute of choice; this will save you from having to edit your Synchronization Rules in the future if you're monitoring for UPN suffixes that aren't your own and you add a new one.  Here is more details on that process: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/connect/how-to-connect-sync-change-the-configuration#enable-synchronization-of-usertype

Comment: do you know if this can match existing external guests? Or can these users be converted to guests? if so is there a powershell or graph api call for this?